# Airflow DockerOperator workaround for Docker-in-Docker Setup

Tags: python, airflow

I deployed Airflow (2.2.4) using Docker and I would like to use the DockerOperator in some of the DAG tasks. I also want to mount a volume with those DockerOperator tasks, but it seems that the **mounts** feature is not available for the Docker-in-Docker setup.

I am trying to think of an elegant workaround since I really need to get the created data (log files and possibly data quality reports by great_expecations) out of this container.

So far I've considered using scp with an SSH key as an environment variable and adding that as an extra command to the DockerOperator. I also looked at the XCom feature, but I don't think it would fit the purpose. Does anyone else have an idea?

Sample task:

```
etl_db_connections_check = DockerOperator(
    task_id="etl_db_connections_check", 
    image='sample_image:latest',
    api_version='auto',
    auto_remove=True,
    environment=environment,
    command='/bin/bash -c \'python /app/src/main.py connection_check\'',
    docker_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock',
    network_mode='bridge',
    docker_conn_id='private_registry',
    xcom_all=True,
    privileged=True,
    mount_tmp_dir=False,
    mounts=[
        Mount(
        source='/data/airflow/dags/sample-logs', 
        target='/logs:rw', 
        type='bind'
    )]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running airflow as a container **on a linux host**: You need to give the airflow user access to your host's `/var/run/docker.sock`. This requires **both**:

1. Adding a volume mapping `/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` in the airflow docker-compose's `x-airflow-common` service.
2. Giving the aiflow user inside the container permission to access it. When you installed `docker` on your host you probably made a "docker" group. Get the GID (a number) of that group (`cat /etc/group | grep docker` should output `docker:x:###:username`). Add the GID ### to the airflow docker-compose's `x-airflow-common` service:

```yaml
  group_add:
   - ###
```

Then restart airflow (`docker-compose kill` followed by `docker-compose up airflow-init && docker-compose up`) and the dag task using`DockerOperator` should work.